# How to erb'up a monitrc configuration file

Tags: erb, monit

Below is my delayed_job monitrc file, i wanted to use it as an erb template so that i can dynamically set the RAILS_ENV variable. Does anyone know how to do it?

```
set daemon  120

check process delayed_job with pidfile /home/rails/public_html/myapp/shared/pids/delayed_job.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/script/delayed_job start"
  stop program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /home/rails/public_html/myapp/current/script/delayed_job stop"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
set daemon <%= interval %>
check process <%= process_name %> with pidfile <%= pidfile %>
  start program = "<%= start_program %>"
  stop program = "<%= stop_program %>"
```

with these variables set accordingly?

Comment: Thats correct. This is how the erb file will look. But i want to know how to run this file from the command line or what kind of a setup we need to do for erb'ed monitrc's.+1